# Calling templated methods on objects from within a templated function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class with one template parameter on it, and it has a method on it that is also templated, with different parameters. Here's a very simple example:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename A>
struct X {
    template <typename R>
    R get() { return R(); }
};
```

In a normal method, I can call `X::get` just fine; for example, this method compiles just fine:

```
int untemplated_function() {
    X<void> x;
    return x.get<int>();
}
```

But! I cannot seem to call this templated method from within a call where template parameter `A` on `X` is itself templated. For example, this method:

```
template <typename B>
int templated_function() {
    X<B> x;
    return x.get<int>();
}
```

Does not compile, giving me the error message:

```
<source>: In function 'int templated_function()':
<source>:12:18: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
     return x.get<int>();
                  ^~~
<source>:12:18: error: expected ';' before 'int'
     return x.get<int>();
                  ^~~
<source>:12:21: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
     return x.get<int>();
```

[Here's the full example on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9UASFs)

It is especially interesting to me that compilation fails even without instantiating the function template (I don't have to call or refer to `templated_function<blah>` for the compilation error to happen). If you remove any of the templates in the example, it compiles fine — for example, if you make `X` untemplated but keep `X::get` templated, it compiles.

How I can call `X<A>::get<int>()` from within a function where `A` is a template parameter?

Comment: You want to use `return x.template get<int>();`, see the duplicate question for more information.